# Do I return None or {} in Python?

Tags: python, function, types, annotations

What should I return in a function that I annotate to return a dict under a condition?

For example,

```py
def function(ls1: list, ls2: list) -> dict:
    if condition:
        # this tells me that the dict will not
        # be possible to make
        return None
    di = {}
    some_di_stuff
    return di
```

Should I return None or a dict with no elements? Because it's like I lied to you if I say that the function returns always a dict and suddenly it returns a None object?

It reminds me to the "Maybe" constructor in Haskell, it would be great.

Comment: You are looking for [`Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional) I think

Comment: I would return empty dict because: (1) you declared that it always return `dict`, (2) it is simpler to work with function which always return the same type of data - even if it is empty dict or empty list -  because later it doesn't need to check `if result is None: ... else: ...` but it always works `for k, v in result.items():`

Comment: If it's fine or important that the function returns a dict you should return an empty dict and annotate it as `dict`. If you're fine with returning either a `dict` or `None` then you should use `Optional` like suggested above or in Python 3.10+ `dict | None` which is more readable. If you always return a dict then whatever depends on this function doesn't need an `isinstance` check so I'd prefer returning an empty `dict`.

Comment: It depends a bit on the context, and the 'semantic' meaning of the function. I'd suggest consider raising an exception instead of returning anything. Can your calling code make sense of a `None` value, or is this really an error case?  Would returning an empty dict risk confusion?  It's impossible to say without more context.

Comment: I agree with @Anentropic. While the OP annotation is definitely wrong (`None` is not a `dict`), it is impossible to say, what solution would be better without more context. If the `condition` were e.g. something directly linked to one (or more) of the arguments, you could even define [`overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload)s for different function calls, one of which always returns `None` while another returns a `dict`. Most of the time having a consistent type seems "nicer" in practice though, but there are many exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

What you are searching for is called [`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union).

```py
from typing import Union

def function(ls1: list, ls2: list) -> Union[dict, None]:
    if condition:
        # this tells me that the dict will not
        # be possible to make
        return None
    di = {}
    some_di_stuff
    return di
```

In this case you are just saying that the function can return a dictionary or `None`.

As suggested by @pavel a function should ideally return a consistent type so empty dict would be preferable in most cases:

```py
def function(ls1: list, ls2: list) -> dict:
    di = {}
    if condition:
        # this tells me that the dict will not
        # be possible to make
        return di
    some_di_stuff
    return di
```

Comment: It's redundant. `Union[<type>, None] == Optional[<type>]` as the very first comment suggested.

Comment: @pavel Yes, but I would type the whole function

Comment: But your pyping suggestion is the same as using either `Union[dict, None]`, `Optional[dict]` or `dict | None`. It also doesn't adress the usability of the resulting function. No one wants to be doing unnecessary checks for `Notetype` if you can avoid it. It's always better for a fucntion to return a constant return type as been suggested in the comments.

Comment: You should make a mention that if the return type can be reasonable expected to be `None` then yes, your suggestion stands. But really, a function should ideally return a consistent type so empty dict would be prefferable in most cases.

Comment: @pavel I agree with you. I edited the answer.

Comment: _"a function should ideally return a consistent type so empty dict would be preferable in most cases"_ I strongly disagree. It's highly context dependent, sometimes it may be the right thing to do but often it would be an antipattern. "Nothing" and "an empty Something" have different meanings.

Comment: I agree with this too. I wanted to know your opinion on this, because I often see things like Optional from Typing and stuff like that, but I prefer being consistent.